# move Sprite with action

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, sprite-kit, skaction

How do I move a sprite automatically back after dragging it somewhere on the screen?

I tried:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(location.x, self.size.height/2);
        self.start.position = newPosition;
        }
    SKAction *moveTo = [SKAction moveToX:self.frame.size.width/2 duration:0.5];
    [self.start runAction:moveTo];
}
```

Comment: what is self.start.position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `moveByX:y:duration:` to initially move your sprite, you can then use `[yourActionName reversedAction];` to move it back to the initial starting point when `touchesEnded:`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -(void)touchesMoved: to place the sprite. Then use -(void)touchesEnded: method to move it back to its origin point.